# Change JetBrains IDE scrollbar color

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to change the white color of the horizontal scroll bar in the editor and the white color of the vertical scrollbar in the python console below:

[image]

If I change to another color scheme it changes, so I know it can be done.

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Comment: If you want to edit the vertical scroll bar's color, navigate to Preferences/Editor/Color Scheme/General/Editor/Vertical Scrollbar, and change the background color of Thumb and Thumb while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Color Scheme in the settings.

Then, you will see an example box with the resulting colour output. Click on the object you want to change its colour.